Как на питоне установить приоритет для выполнения потоков?
Я использую Python и библиотеку threading. Как разным потокам можно выдать разный объём вычислительных ресурсов? В питоне распаралеливание это иллюзия, насколько я знаю, и потоки просто сменяют друг друга. Как сделать так, что бы, допустим, первый поток работал 70% времени, второй 20% времени, а третий 10% времени?
Мне не подходит вариант с time.sleep(), я использую распаралеливание для запуска нескольких экземпляров телеграм-ботов и вставлять паузу там просто негде. Библиотека multiprocessing так же не подходит, так как в ней могут возникат конфликты доступа к общим ресурсам и несогласованность данных.

Проценты и GIL трудно совместимы, может быть стоит ставить более реалистичные задачи? Несколько более реально, что бы более приоритетный поток оказывался первым в деле получения GIL. Но это зависит от используемой ОС, особенно, в части спин-локов, вроде как у Linux были проблемы по этой части. Впрочем, только эксперименты могут подтвердить или опровергнуть сиё. Как бы, с помощью ctypes можно получить интерфейс функции pthread_setschedprio()  и нескольких других и попытаться их использовать.
